# SugarCRM Slow Queries (on MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sugarcrm, filesort

We are using SugarCRM with a MySQL 5.5 database and are seeing poor performance with a frequently occuring query.

Unfortunately re-ordering of the query is not possible due to the nature of SugarCRM. I've attempted optimizations via indexing, but I haven't gotten very far.  That said, I'm not very proficient at doing such either.

Can you suggest any alternate indexing that will improve our results and avoid the filesort?

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cases.id, cases.case_number, cases.status, cases.name,
   cases.date_entered, 
   cases.assigned_user_id, cases.system_id
FROM cases
INNER JOIN team_sets_teams tst ON tst.team_set_id = cases.team_set_id
INNER JOIN team_memberships team_memberships ON tst.team_id = team_memberships.team_id
  AND team_memberships.user_id = 'f09ab586-986c-a6f6-0c2e-4d1f1432b6ec' 
  AND team_memberships.deleted=0
ORDER BY cases.case_number DESC
LIMIT 0,11;
```

EXPLAIN results:

```
select_type table             type possible_keys                                   key                 ref                               rows Extra
SIMPLE      team_memberships  ref  team_id,user_id,idx_team_membership             idx_team_membership const                             26   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
SIMPLE      tst               ref  idx_ud_set_id,idx_ud_team_id,idx_ud_team_set_id idx_ud_team_id      sugarcrm.team_memberships.team_id 7    Using where
SIMPLE      cases             ref  idx_cases_tmst_id,idx_cases_created             idx_cases_tmst_id   sugarcrm.tst.team_set_id          5    Using where
```

Table Definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `cases` (
`id` char(36) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`date_entered` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`modified_user_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_by` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` text,
`deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
`assigned_user_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`team_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`case_number` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`priority` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`resolution` text,
`system_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`work_log` text,
`account_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`portal_viewable` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
`team_set_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`parent_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`parent_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Cases',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `casesnumk` (`case_number`),
UNIQUE KEY `case_number` (`case_number`,`system_id`),
KEY `idx_case_name` (`name`),
KEY `idx_account_id` (`account_id`),
KEY `idx_cases_stat_del` (`assigned_user_id`,`status`,`deleted`),
KEY `idx_cases_tmst_id` (`team_set_id`),
KEY `date_modified` (`date_modified`),
KEY `modified_user_id` (`modified_user_id`),
KEY `idx_cases_created` (`team_set_id`,`date_entered`),
KEY `team_id` (`team_id`),
KEY `idx_cases_del` (`deleted`),
KEY `idx_cases_date_entered` (`date_entered`),
KEY `idx_cases_status` (`status`),
KEY `idx_cases_parent_id` (`parent_id`),
KEY `idx_cases_priority` (`priority`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `team_sets_teams` (
`id` char(36) NOT NULL,
`team_set_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`team_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `idx_ud_set_id` (`team_set_id`,`team_id`),
KEY `idx_ud_team_id` (`team_id`),
KEY `idx_ud_team_set_id` (`team_set_id`),
KEY `idx_tst_deleted` (`deleted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `team_memberships` (
`id` char(36) NOT NULL,
`team_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`explicit_assign` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
`implicit_assign` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
`date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `date_modified` (`date_modified`),
KEY `team_id` (`team_id`),
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
KEY `idx_team_membership` (`user_id`,`team_id`,`deleted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: The fact that all of the IDs are `CHAR(36)`s definitely doesn't help, especially since the tables are using `InnoDB`, but you probably can't change that.  Some indexes could probably be added to help this specific query, but they may not make a huge difference.  How slow is slow?

Comment: You are correct that we can't change that.

Typically the query takes 5 seconds on a server with lots of CPU and RAM. But it is constantly run as part of a dashlet by many users and should be capable of completing < 1 second.

Comment: Are you sure the filesort is where MySQL is spending the most time?  Can you profile the query and update your question with those results?  I'd be surprised if the filesort is really where the bottleneck is.  That said, SugarCRM was definitely not designed to be efficient.

Comment: That was illuminating. Now I must figure out what to do next.

`starting                        0.000015
...
Creating tmp table              0.000029
executing                       0.000003
Copying to tmp table            0.891442
converting HEAP to MyISAM       0.498635
Copying to tmp table on disk    8.596956
Sorting result                  0.287117
logging slow query              0.000002
logging slow query              0.000073
cleaning up                     0.000006
`

Comment: What's slowing the query is this "ORDER BY cases.case_number DESC". So what you can do is under listviewdefs.php add at the top the ability to check if there are criteria from search form. If so, then ignore as it'll be quick, if not, add $_REQUEST['order_by'] = 'DO_NO_SORT'; . I hope that'll fix the issue for you. This is a really bad product from SugarCRM, not good for big data.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems while switching from Ubuntu 10.04 server to 12.04. Because InnoDB as default engine for the newer MySQL version packaged in Ubuntu 12.04. I played a little with MySQL server settings like query_cache_size, innodb_buffer_pool_size, innodb_log_buffer_size and it dramatically improved performance.

Comment: I've increased RAM and many tuning options to reduce the need to write to temp, but it seems to be a losing battle, returning too many rows as part of the joins.

Comment: @user2246576 If that's the case, and changing the settings does not prevent copying to a temp table, then it looks like your only option would be upgrading your server to use an SSD to minimize your write & read times.  Unless you want to try and modify the SugarCRM core...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following indexes:

```
mysql> show indexes from team_memberships;
+------------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table            | Non_unique | Key_name               | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| team_memberships |          0 | PRIMARY                |            1 | id          | A         |         665 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| team_memberships |          1 | idx_team_membership    |            1 | user_id     | A         |         665 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| team_memberships |          1 | idx_team_membership    |            2 | team_id     | A         |         665 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| team_memberships |          1 | idx_teammemb_team_user |            1 | team_id     | A         |         665 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| team_memberships |          1 | idx_teammemb_team_user |            2 | user_id     | A         |         665 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| team_memberships |          1 | idx_team_deleted_user  |            1 | user_id     | A         |         665 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| team_memberships |          1 | idx_team_deleted_user  |            2 | deleted     | A         |         665 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| team_memberships |          1 | idx_team_deleted_user  |            3 | team_id     | A         |         665 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+



mysql> show indexes from cases;
+-------+------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name           | Seq_in_index | Column_name      | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| cases |          0 | PRIMARY            |            1 | id               | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| cases |          0 | casesnumk          |            1 | case_number      | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| cases |          0 | case_number        |            1 | case_number      | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| cases |          0 | case_number        |            2 | system_id        | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| cases |          1 | idx_case_name      |            1 | name             | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| cases |          1 | idx_account_id     |            1 | account_id       | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| cases |          1 | idx_cases_stat_del |            1 | assigned_user_id | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| cases |          1 | idx_cases_stat_del |            2 | status           | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| cases |          1 | idx_cases_stat_del |            3 | deleted          | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| cases |          1 | idx_cases_tmst_id  |            1 | team_set_id      | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| cases |          1 | deleted            |            1 | deleted          | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| cases |          1 | team_id            |            1 | team_id          | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+

mysql> show indexes from team_sets_teams;
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name           | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| team_sets_teams |          1 | idx_ud_set_id      |            1 | team_set_id | A         |          13 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| team_sets_teams |          1 | idx_ud_set_id      |            2 | team_id     | A         |          13 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| team_sets_teams |          1 | idx_ud_team_id     |            1 | team_id     | A         |          13 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| team_sets_teams |          1 | deleted            |            1 | deleted     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| team_sets_teams |          1 | idx_ud_team_set_id |            1 | team_set_id | A         |          13 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time is being spent copying the temp table to disk.  This happens when the data in the temp table is too big for MySQL to hold in RAM per its configuration settings.

Try increasing your `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` MySQL settings.  This should prevent the temp table from being moved to disk, which should speed up the query (if your server has enough RAM to handle it; this will depend on how many simultaneous users you have in SugarCRM).

The bottleneck here now looks to be your disk i/o - upgrading the server to us an SSD will also have a performance benefit, if not for this query (with the above settings increased) but for SugarCRM on the whole.  If you can't increase the above settings to keep the temp tables in RAM, then getting an SSD would be the next best thing.